# how to convert this result of calculation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, integer, double

wanna know how to show this result like int number

```
var symbol = data[index]["symbol"];
  double cureentprice = datarates["price"]["$symbol"];////this double is 1.17150

 double enrty = double.parse(data[index]["entryprice"]);////this is 1.17100

 double lo = cureentprice - enrty ;//i got like this result 0.00050
```

as you see above i got the result 0.00050 but i need it like this 50

any idea to do somthing like that??

Comment: Multiply by 10000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This. Maybe This should Help. If this doesn't work then let me know.

```
var symbol = data[index]["symbol"];
   double cureentprice = datarates["price"]["$symbol"];////this double is 1.17150

 double enrty = double.parse(data[index]["entryprice"]);////this is 1.17100

 // double lo = cureentprice - enrty ;//i got like this result 0.00050

 int scale = 100000;
 double lo = currentPrice - enrty;
 var value1 = (lo * scale).floor(); 
 var value2 = (lo * scale).ceil();
 print(value1);
 print(value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first scale and then round-off using floor() or ceil() function to get desired output.

```
 double currentPrice = 1.17150;
 double enrty = 1.17100;
 int scale = 100000;
 double lo = currentPrice - enrty;
 print((lo * scale).floor()); //prints 49
 print((lo * scale).ceil()); //prints 50
```